# How is my app notified with Webhooks?Do I need to poll the recipient URL?

Tags: rest, api, webhooks, polling

From [this](https://www.jamesward.com/2014/06/11/testing-webhooks-was-a-pain-so-i-fixed-the-glitch):

> A Webhook is a way for you to define a URL that is called by another
>   service when a particular event occurs. For example, you can configure
>   your repo on GitHub to have a Webhook that calls http://foo.com/pr
>   when a new Pull Request is created. The old alternative to this is
>   polling (bad).

How is then the data reaching my application? Don't I have to poll the (http://foo.com/pr) URL for changes?

Comment: You need to make a public API for the webhook to call when that event occurs.

Comment: In the example, foo.com is your application.

Comment: @dmulter That's pretty deep!It hadn't occurred to me.You mean that I can handle the data as a like a simple GET request to my URL?

Comment: Yes but a webhook is typically a POST.

Answer (score 0):

Polling - You call the api at **regular intervals** to check whether a change has happened or not.

Webhooks - Your service(API endpoint which you provide on creating the webhook) will be **notified whenever a change happens** In any of the resources you want to monitor in the third party server.

The main difference is in case of webhooks, your server has to work to check for updates even if no updates happen in the third party site. Rather webhooks will automatically notify you once when a change happens.

Example : To check if a particular user has posted a new tweet, you can poll every 15 minutes to check if a new tweet has been made using the gettweets api provided by Twitter. On the other hand Twitter supports webhooks(which you have to register for monitoring) which will notify to the API endpoint defined by you if the particular user tweets.